# Workaround for Snowflake compiler errors

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sometimes the Snowflake SQL compiler tries to be too smart for its own good. This is a follow-up to a [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182388/udtfs-cant-compile-or-execute-outside-of-trivial-invocation), where a clever solution was provided for my given use-case, but have run into some limitations for that solution.

A brief background; I have a JS-UDTF that takes 3 float arguments to return rows representing a series `GENERATE_SERIES(FLOAT,FLOAT,FLOAT)`, and a SQL-UDTF `GENERATE_SERIES(INT,INT,INT)` that cast the params to floats, invokes the JS-UDTF, and then the result back to ints. My original version for this wrapper UDTF was:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_series(FIRST_VALUE INTEGER, LAST_VALUE INTEGER, STEP_VALUE INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE (GS_VALUE INTEGER)
AS
$$
SELECT GS_VALUE::INTEGER AS GS_VALUE FROM table(generate_series(FIRST_VALUE::DOUBLE,LAST_VALUE::DOUBLE,STEP_VALUE::DOUBLE))
$$;
```

Which would fail in most conditions where the input were not constants, e.g.:

```
WITH report_params AS (
  SELECT
    1::integer as first_value,
    3::integer as last_value,
    1::integer AS step_value
)      
SELECT
  *
FROM
    report_params, table(
  generate_series(
    first_value,
    last_value,
    step_value
  )
)
```

Would return error:

```
SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated
```

The provided solution to trick the SQL compiler to behave was to encapsulate the function params into a VALUES table and cross-join the inner UDTF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_series_int(FIRST_VALUE INTEGER, LAST_VALUE INTEGER, STEP_VALUE INTEGER)
    RETURNS TABLE (GS_VALUE INTEGER)
    AS
$$
    SELECT GS_VALUE::INTEGER AS GS_VALUE 
    FROM (VALUES (first_value, last_value, step_value)), 
         table(generate_series(first_value::double,last_value::double,step_value::double))
$$;
```

This worked lovely for most invocations, however I've discovered a situation where the SQL compiler is at it again. Here is a simplified example that reproduces the problem:

```
WITH report_params AS (
  SELECT
    1::integer AS first_value,
    DATEDIFF('DAY','2020-01-01'::date,'2020-02-01'::date)::integer AS last_value,
    1::integer AS step_value
)      
SELECT
  *
FROM
  report_params, table(
  COMMON.FN.generate_series(
    first_value,
    last_value,
    step_value
  )
);
```

This results in the error:

```
SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [CORRELATION(SYS_VW.LAST_VALUE_3)] in VALUES clause
```

The error seems obvious enough (I think) that the compiler is trying to embed the function code into the outer queries treating the function like a macro before runtime.

The answer at this point might just be that I am asking too much out of Snowflake's current capabilities, but in the interest of learning and continuing to build out what I think is a very helpful UDF library, am curious if there is a solution I am missing.

Comment: I might be missing something, but where is `SYS_VW.LAST_VALUE_3` coming from?  I don't see it anywhere in what you've provided in your question.

Comment: @MikeWalton I believe that's the compiler renaming column names to be unique in the final optimized query to run. I frequently see _2, _3, _4, _5, etc. suffixes in my errors, usually in that SYS_VW namespace. I assume it's because SF algorithms rearrange and re-nest so many things that it's the easiest way to make sure there's no naming collisions.

Comment: (More specifically I think that's especially common with CTEs that it's converting to subqueries; I just tried moving my report_params CTE into a subquery of the main SELECT and LAST_VALUE instead of LAST_VALUE_3 returns in the error now )

Comment: yes in general, clever tricks that end-around the compiler limitations, resurface when you add more complexity, and it rearranges the inner part,thus inducing the original problem again.

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is you have written a correlated sub query.

```
WITH report_params AS (
  SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, 30, 1)
    v(first_value,last_value, step_value) 
)      
SELECT
  *
FROM
  report_params, table(
  COMMON.FN.generate_series(
    first_value,
    last_value,
    step_value
  )
);
```

as when you add a second row to your CTE

```
WITH report_params AS (
  SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, 30, 1),
    (2, 40, 2)
    v(first_value,last_value, step_value) 
)      
SELECT
  *
FROM
  report_params, table(
  COMMON.FN.generate_series(
    first_value,
    last_value,
    step_value
  )
);
```

it becomes more obvious this is correlated, which is not so obvious who snowflake should execute it.

which for the above data would ideal look like (if it was valid SQL)

```
WITH report_params AS (
   SELECT *
      ,mod(v.first_value,v.step_value) as mod_offset
      FROM VALUES
        (0, 5, 20, 1),
        (1, 3, 15, 3),
        (2, 4, 15, 3),
        (3, 5, 15, 3)
        v(id, first_value,last_value, step_value) 
), report_ranges AS (
  SELECT min(first_value) as mmin,
    max(last_value) as mmax
  FROM report_params
  WHERE first_value <= last_value AND step_value > 0
), all_range AS (
  SELECT 
   row_number() over (order by seq8()) + rr.mmin - 1 as seq
  FROM report_ranges rr, 
  TABLE(GENERATOR( ROWCOUNT => (rr.mmax - rr.mmin) + 1 ))
)
SELECT 
  ar.seq
  ,rp.id, rp.first_value, rp.last_value, rp.step_value, rp.mod_offset
FROM all_range as ar
JOIN report_params as rp ON ar.seq BETWEEN rp.first_value AND rp.last_value AND mod(ar.seq, rp.step_value) = rp.mod_offset
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

but if your generating it in a stored procedure (or externally) could be substituted into

```
 WITH report_params AS (
   SELECT *
      ,mod(v.first_value,v.step_value) as mod_offset
      FROM VALUES
        (0, 5, 20, 1),
        (1, 3, 15, 3),
        (2, 4, 15, 3),
        (3, 5, 15, 3)
        v(id, first_value,last_value, step_value) 
), all_range AS (
  SELECT 
   row_number() over (order by seq8()) + 3 /*min*/ - 1 as seq
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR( ROWCOUNT => (20/*max*/ - 3/*min*/) + 1 ))
)
SELECT 
  ar.seq
  ,rp.id
  ,rp.first_value, rp.last_value, rp.step_value, rp.mod_offset
FROM all_range as ar
JOIN report_params as rp ON ar.seq BETWEEN rp.first_value AND rp.last_value AND mod(ar.seq, rp.step_value) = rp.mod_offset
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

giving:

```
SEQ ID  FIRST_VALUE LAST_VALUE  STEP_VALUE  MOD_OFFSET
5   0   5   20  1   0
6   0   5   20  1   0
7   0   5   20  1   0
8   0   5   20  1   0
9   0   5   20  1   0
10  0   5   20  1   0
11  0   5   20  1   0
12  0   5   20  1   0
13  0   5   20  1   0
14  0   5   20  1   0
15  0   5   20  1   0
16  0   5   20  1   0
17  0   5   20  1   0
18  0   5   20  1   0
19  0   5   20  1   0
20  0   5   20  1   0
3   1   3   15  3   0
6   1   3   15  3   0
9   1   3   15  3   0
12  1   3   15  3   0
15  1   3   15  3   0
4   2   4   15  3   1
7   2   4   15  3   1
10  2   4   15  3   1
13  2   4   15  3   1
5   3   5   15  3   2
8   3   5   15  3   2
11  3   5   15  3   2
14  3   5   15  3   2
```

The problem I cannot guess at, is it feels like you ether trying to hide some complexity behind the table functions JS functions, or have made thing over complex for an unstated reason.

[edit speaking to the 1-9 comment]
the major difference between a `generate_series` and `GENERATOR` is the former is almost a UDF or CTE and in snowflake you have to have the GENERATOR in it own sub-select or you will get messed up results.

```
 with s1 as (
  SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by seq8()) -1 as seq
  FROM 
  TABLE(GENERATOR( ROWCOUNT => 3 ))
), s2 as (
  SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by seq8()) -1 as seq
  FROM 
  TABLE(GENERATOR( ROWCOUNT => 3 ))
)
select s1.seq as a, s2.seq as b
from s1, s2
order by 1,2;
```

gives 9 rows of the two data mixed, like you not you want.
where-as

```
with s1 as (
  SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by seq8()) -1 as seq
  FROM 
  TABLE(GENERATOR( ROWCOUNT => 3 ))
)
SELECT 
  row_number() over (order by seq8()) -1 as a
  ,s1.seq as b
FROM 
TABLE(GENERATOR( ROWCOUNT => 3 )), s1;
```

give 1-9, because the GENERATOR (the creator of rows) has been crossed with the other data, before the sequence code has run..

Another version of the original solution provided, is

```
WITH report_params AS (
   SELECT *
      ,trunc(div0((last_value-first_value),step_value)) as steps
      FROM VALUES
        (0, 5, 20, 1),
        (1, 3, 15, 3),
        (2, 4, 15, 3),
        (3, 5, 15, 3)
        v(id, first_value,last_value, step_value) 
), large_range AS (
  SELECT 
   row_number() over (order by seq8()) -1 as seq
  FROM 
  TABLE(GENERATOR( ROWCOUNT => 1000 ))
)
select rp.id
    ,rp.first_value + (lr.seq*rp.step_value) as val
from report_params as rp
join large_range as lr on lr.seq <= rp.steps
order by 1,2;
```

which I like more as the nature of the mixing is more clear. But it still speaks to the mindset difference between snowflake and other RDB. In postgress there is no cost to doing per-row operations, because it was born of an era where it was all per-row operations, but snowflake has no per-row options, and because it cannot do things on each row, it can do many rows independently. It means all expressions of per-row, need to be moved to the front and then joined. Thus what the above is trying to show.

Comment: Thanks for the insight re: correlated query that makes sense. Re: purpose, the problem is with all due love to Snowflake and appreciation for its capabilities overall, their GENERATOR() is hot garbage; issue #1 being that it can only take hardcoded static constants as its input. You're correct i'm trying to hide some complexity, this lib is to emulate the generate_series() functionality in postgres, for consumption by BI teams who don't have a fair shot at grasping the built-in generator. The query I provided was contrived to reproduce the error concisely; actual use-cases aren't as silly.

Comment: while I agree `generator()` seems rather prickly, trying to hide it seems almost more impossible/dangerous. Where-as putting it into a CTE() and almost given out some working examples might end with less paper cuts.

Comment: to defend snowflake more, I really like it as it runs SQL that never completes (on our PostgreSQL instances), the only cost is thinking a little more functional, but at the same time once you set it likes to do big chains of map with some reduce steps and joins are merge sorts, fun to build up large functional transforms. The _gross_ part of `GENERATOR()` is it only gives you some rows, and it's up to you to fill those rows out, but like most SF, each step is up to you, so if you don't need something don't put it in. It's a no free lunch, but you know whats in the sandwich as you put it there

Comment: for sure, snowflake as a whole is great and has solved many of my problems and worth the drawbacks; my venting is with GENERATOR() in particular. To clarify, my UDF doesn't implement GENERATOR(), it does a complete end-run around it and calls a primitive javascript while loop (for my typical series lengths not a performance issue); I agree too many bodies in GENERATOR() to try to encapsulate, e.g. if you generate 3 rows and later cross join it with 3 other rows, it runs away with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, not 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 as you'd see in pgsql (and not in predictable order you can solve w/mod).

Comment: what you are describing by getting 1-9 sounds like you have mixed your generator block with the cross join

Comment: got it, thank you for the update with the explanation about how the generator operates. this should def give me more flexibility using the original generator. thanks!